# Any tips on fighting the tank of Extra Ops 69 (BTR-60 PA) in no-kill playthought?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

I am aiming for the no-kill trophy, and like the added difficulty of recovering soldier after putting them to sleep, but I am struggling on this mission.

Internet say there is 20 escort (which mean 5 waves of backup), and the leader to take out if I want to take it out without killing.

The problem is, as far as I am, I can t take more than 12 Fulton, which mean either kill the 8 escort remaining, or take them out while in the path of the tank so it crush them (ethically questionnable and quite hard to do for one, so for eight...).

Either throwing and set support give me ammo and ration, but no additionnal Fulton, so...

Is there any other way to take them out of the battlefield? Or get more Fulton? (I m already rank 3, but I lack the blueprint for rank 4. Even then, I don t know if it will go up to 20 Fulton!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just waited to get the blueprint for the Carl Gustav (Fulton Recovery) (killing everybody in the way) and the Fulton Mine, so I had enought Fulton for everyone.

It does is sufficient for everygroups, but is not easy to pull of (and quite long). If you want to S rank everything, wait for the Infinity Bandana, Hold On, Fulton Mine, fire on the Fulton Mine with the tranquilizer gun, repeat.